# calling [UIAlertView show] freezes UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit

The following code presents an alert view. the `[alert show]` method has to be run on the main thread and takes about 0.5 seconds to complete on my iPhone 5. This is kind of annoying as it freezes the UI, but it only happens the first time its called. After that, it shows immediately.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Type Something:", nil)
                                               message:nil delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No", nil)
                                     otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Done", nil), nil];

[alert show];
```

If I add a text field to the alert view by calling `alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;` the `[alert show];` method takes about 5 seconds to complete on my iPhone 5. This is 5 seconds that the UI is frozen. I could just display a loading message to the user but I would rather find a way that allows user interaction. Is there any way to call `[alert show];` without freezing the UI?

Comment: There's something else going on here... In most situations a UIAlertView won't freeze the UI. Where is it in your code? How's it being called? etc.

Comment: And you should be using UIAlertController if it's iOS8: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html

Comment: It's currently being triggered by a button action. It's the only code inside the action.

Comment: Its deployment target is iOS 5.1.1

Comment: If it's running on iOS 8, try using UIAlertController. You should still use UIAlertView when it's iOS <8.

Comment: I just tried using UIAlertController and I still get the same results.

Comment: Wrap it in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ });`

Comment: I already tried async, didn't change anything.
To make sure it was nothing else I put it into a blank project, and I've uploaded it to github: https://github.com/meech-ward/AlertViews.git
The first time I tap the button it takes about 5 seconds on my iPhone 5 and about 3 seconds on my iPad 1 to show the alert.

Comment: OK, then the delay is coming from finding your `NSLocalizedString`s from your "Localizable.strings".

Comment: I took that out and nothing changed.

Comment: @Sam What did you take out? Did you replace all of your `NSLocalizedString`s with basic NSStrings?

Comment: Sorry, I replaced the NSLocalizedStrings with normal NSStrings.

Comment: https://github.com/meech-ward/AlertViews/blob/master/test/ViewController.m

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65532/discussion-between-sam-and-lyndsey-scott).

Comment: Are you implementing the delegate methods of UIAlertView? could be that your code is trying to find/run delegate method, but can't find one.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solved this problem?